# SOAP request failing on production server

Tags: php, soap

I'm using a SOAP webservice for VAT validity check.
It works fine on my workstation and on a test server, but not on the production server. There it throws an Exception:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $client = new \SoapClient('http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl', array('exceptions' => true));
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl"
in php shell code on line 1
PHP Warning:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl"
in php shell code:1
Stack trace:
#0 php shell code(1): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://ec.europ...', Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in php shell code on line 1
```

All 3 machines run the same OS (Ubuntu 12.04) and PHP (5.3.10) version. The package php-soap (0.12.0-2) is installed on all of them.
I can wget the wsdl file from the production server.
This issue already persists for several days now, so it's not something temporary.

If I download the wsdl and use the local file path instead of the remote http path, it works on the production server too. However that's not a nice solution.

Any idea what else I could check for?

Comment: What is the [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) setting there? Also, depending an nastyness of that soap-server, I've had luck in the past by defining _any_ [`user_agent`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent) (does not matter what you enter, as long as it's not empty for some servers apparently...)

Comment: Ooh, and check whether your [`wsdl_cache_dir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soap.configuration.php#ini.soap.wsdl-cache-dir) is writeable.

Comment: ./apache2/php.ini:allow_url_fopen = On
wsdl_cache_dir is /tmp which is writable.
Will try user_agent, thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am still stuck here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spend more time on the issue as it was not strictly necessary to have the feature.